Validate el-form-item (element-plus) with Laravel result from backend without using rules
I have the following vue3 component:
<template>
    <el-form @submit.prevent="save" ref="form__ref" :model="record">
        <el-form-item>
            <el-button native-type="submit">Save</el-button>
        </el-form-item>
        <el-form-item label="Label" prop="label">
            <el-input v-model="record.label" id="label"/>
        </el-form-item>
    </el-form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
// IMPORTS
...

// PROPS
...

// CONSTANTES
const record = ref<MyInterface>(new MyClass());

// REFERENCES
const form__ref = ref<InstanceType<typeof ElForm>>();

// METHODS
const save = async (): Promise<void> => {
    form__ref.value?.clearValidate();

    try {
        await MyService.store(record.value);
        
        ...
    } catch (error) {
        // error = {"label": ["one message", "two message", ...]}
        for (const field in error) {
            const item = form__ref.value?.fields.find((f) => f.prop === field);

            if (item) {
                item.validateMessage = error[field].join(', ');
                item.validateState = 'error';
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>

I want to validate each el-form-item according to the validation returned from the backend by Laravel (all inside the catch). The instruction item.validateState = 'error' highlights in red, however I cannot get the error message to appear. I would appreciate your help.
Thanks
PD: HERE test.
